# Issue loading images for tensorfow from colab folder

Tags: tensorflow

I made a folder in colab called "pics" [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPOA9.png) which contains png images and I want to make a test/train split. I thought loading them like this

```
data = pathlib.Path('/content/pics')
```

and then using image_dataset_from_directory like this

```
train_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data,
  validation_split=0.3,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(165, 1310),
  batch_size=30)
```

would work, but I get the error 'No images found in directory /content/pics.'

Answer (score 1):

Your image folder path is not accessible by Google Colab.
Try mounting your google drive in colab using:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/GoogleDrive/')
```

Keep your images folder inside this googleDrive in any folder and give this path in colab to access these images as below:

```
data = '/content/GoogleDrive/My Drive/dataset/'
```

Note : (Make sure you give path till one directory above to the exact images folder)

For instance, suppose you have images inside this `pics` folder `'/content/GoogleDrive/My Drive/dataset/pics/'`

then give path till `dataset` folder, like this :`'/content/GoogleDrive/My Drive/dataset'`